# python Chatroom/Codehelp through the terminal

Tags: python

I created a system that allows individuals to ask questions about code, and chat. I wanted to make this system smaller and better because this is easy to bypass for some reason.

The modules/packages I used for this chatroom project

```py
import os
import time
```

Now the actual script that contains about 56 lines of code!

```py
print("Codehelp || Question through a terminal.")
#### Codehelp Variables
chat = open('publiclogs.txt','r')
name = input("Enter Username: ")
crown = ""
owner = False
#### Codehelp Scripts
if name == "":
  print("\nINVALID! Name must not be Empty..\n")
  time.sleep(2)
  exit()
while True: 
  with open('publiclogs.txt','a') as chat_txt:
    chat_txt.close()
  chat = open('chat.txt','r')
  print(chat.read())
  message = input("Enter Your message: ")
  os.system("clear")
  if message.lower() == "":
    os.system("clear")
    print("You must type something in order to send a message\n")
    input("Press enter to continue ")
    os.system("clear")
  elif message.lower() == ".ask":
    title = input("Enter title of Question. Also be specific: ")
    description = input("Enter description: ")
    tags = input("Enter TAGS. Seperate by ',': ")
    os.system("clear")
    with open('question.txt','a') as ask_txt:
      ask_txt.write(f'TITLE: {title}\n')
      ask_txt.write(f'DESCRIPTION: {description}\n')
      ask_txt.write(f'TAGS: {tags}\n')
      ask_txt.write(f'Written by {name}\n')
      ask_txt.write(f'-------------------\n')
      ask_txt.close()
    with open('publiclogs.txt','a') as chat_txt:
      chat_txt.write(f'New Question has been asked! View question.txt!\n')
      chat_txt.close()
  elif message.lower() == ".login":
    print("Welcome to the Admin log-in!")
    time.sleep(2)
    password = input("What's the Password: ")
    print("Removed from Codehelp Currently..")
  else:
      if owner == True:
        with open('chat.txt','a') as chat_txt:
          chat_txt.write(f'{crown} {name}:{message}\n')
          chat_txt.close()
      else: 
        with open('chat.txt','a') as chat_txt:
          chat_txt.write(f'{name}: {message}\n')
          chat_txt.close()
```

What could I do to improve this code?

Comment: How is this a chat room? Is the file mapped to an NFS mount or something?

Answer (score 1):

- The original value of the `chat` variable appears to be unused - you just open the publiclogs.txt file but never use or close it
- Every pass through the loop you open and then immediately close the "publiclogs.txt" file again. That doesn't seem very useful
- Using `open` with `with` statements is good and is usually the way to go, but sometimes you use `open` on its own which just increases the risk of opening a file and forgetting to close it - you rarely want to do that
- On a related note, you don't need to manually close files if you opened them in the heading of a `with` statement. The `ask_txt.close()` and `chat_txt.close()` lines in the `.ask` part are unnecessary
- You keep re-opening "chat.txt" each pass through the loop. If you want to go back to the start of the file you usually want to use `chat.seek(0)` rather than re-opening the file. There *are* situations where closing and re-opening a file is warranted, but I'm not sure whether this is one of them
- A minor issue, but I find it annoying that both the variable `chat` and the variable `chat_txt` can sometimes refer to the file "chat.txt" and sometimes to the file "publiclogs.txt", with no obvious pattern as for which one is used when. It makes the logic harder to follow

Comment: _chat.seek(0), not re-open the file_ - usually I would agree, but in this specific case if the file is expected to be shared between multiple processes it's actually safer to close and re-open on each loop.

Answer (score 0):

I have carefully read all of your code and I would like to propose some changes, in line with the PEP8 good practice convention:

- ideally, the indentation is a multiple of 4;
- it is not necessary to use multiple '#' to comment a line;
- boolean expressions like `if owner == True` can be simplified to `if owner`;
- On line 27, I replaced `Seperate` with `Separate`;
- You can replace `-------------------` with `{"-" * 20}`;
- It is also possible to avoid over-repeating `ask_txt.write` by inserting newline after `\n`;
- 1 blank space after each comma;
- 1 blank paragraph at the end of everything.

Here is the entire code including the modifications I suggested:

```py
print("Codehelp || Question through a terminal.")
# Codehelp Variables
chat = open('publiclogs.txt', 'r')
name = input("Enter Username: ")
crown = ""
owner = False
# Codehelp Scripts
if name == "":
    print("\nINVALID! Name must not be Empty..\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    exit()
while True:
    with open('publiclogs.txt', 'a') as chat_txt:
        chat_txt.close()
    chat = open('chat.txt', 'r')
    print(chat.read())
    message = input("Enter Your message: ")
    os.system("clear")
    if message.lower() == "":
        os.system("clear")
        input("You must type something in order to send a message\n"
              "Press enter to continue ")
        os.system("clear")
    elif message.lower() == ".ask":
        title = input("Enter title of Question. Also be specific: ")
        description = input("Enter description: ")
        tags = input("Enter TAGS. Separate by ',': ")
        os.system("clear")
        with open('question.txt', 'a') as ask_txt:
            ask_txt.write(f'TITLE: {title}\n'
                          f'DESCRIPTION: {description}\n'
                          f'TAGS: {tags}\n'
                          f'Written by {name}\n'
                          f'{"-" * 20}')
            ask_txt.close()
        with open('publiclogs.txt', 'a') as chat_txt:
            chat_txt.write(f'New Question has been asked! View question.txt!\n')
            chat_txt.close()
    elif message.lower() == ".login":
        print("Welcome to the Admin log-in!")
        time.sleep(2)
        password = input("What's the Password: ")
        print("Removed from Codehelp Currently..")
    else:
        if owner:
            with open('chat.txt', 'a') as chat_txt:
                chat_txt.write(f'{crown} {name}:{message}\n')
                chat_txt.close()
        else:
            with open('chat.txt', 'a') as chat_txt:
                chat_txt.write(f'{name}: {message}\n')
                chat_txt.close()
```

Here is the complete documentation. [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: I have rejected two of your previously approved suggested edits. You are not allowed to edit code in questions - [1](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6124) [2](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6947). Additionally, please refrain from suggesting the same edit twice in the future. However, please feel free to suggest [the text changes in this edit](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/253162/revisions) again if you don't edit the code. (so you get +2 rep) If you edit the code your suggestion will be rejected.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that and I really appreciate.

Comment: This is doing the same thing a different way but with the same effort if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

- Your initial `open()` is redundant and can be deleted
- `crown` is unused because `owner` is hard-coded to `False`
- Consider using `pathlib` which makes several things in your code more convenient
- Your `sleep` calls hinder rather than enhance usability and can be deleted
- `os.system('clear')` is not cross-platform, and anyway it offers no usability benefit, so that can be deleted, too
- Your `with / close` pattern implies a double-close, which is incorrect. The point of `with` is that it already guarantees a `close`.
- Use `getpass` instead of `input` for the administrative password, to prevent over-the-shoulder
- Instead of killing the entire process on invalid username input, consider adding a validation loop

### Suggested

```
from getpass import getpass
from pathlib import Path

CHAT_PATH = Path('chat.txt')
QUESTION_PATH = Path('question.txt')
LOG_PATH = Path('publiclogs.txt')

print("Codehelp || Question through a terminal.")

while True:
    name = input("Username: ")
    if name != "":
        break
    print("Invalid: name must not be empty.")


while True:
    if CHAT_PATH.exists():
        print(CHAT_PATH.read_text())

    message = input("Message: ")
    command = message.lower()

    if command == ".ask":
        title = input("Question title: ")
        description = input("Description: ")
        tags = input("Tags, separated by ',': ")

        with QUESTION_PATH.open('a') as ask_txt:
            ask_txt.write(
                f'TITLE: {title}\n'
                f'DESCRIPTION: {description}\n'
                f'TAGS: {tags}\n'
                f'Written by {name}\n'
                f'-------------------\n'
            )

        with LOG_PATH.open('a') as log_txt:
            log_txt.write(f'New question has been asked! View {QUESTION_PATH}\n')

    elif command == ".login":
        print("Welcome to the Admin log-in!")
        password = getpass()
        print("Removed from Codehelp currently..")

    else:
        with CHAT_PATH.open('a') as chat_txt:
            chat_txt.write(f'{name}: {message}\n')
```

Comment: consider using a reference variable for key words you want to highlight as a function. for instance if you use KEYWORDS_ = [ask, message, send, take] etc.. then reference them through comprehension, in_list = x for x in KEYWORDS if x == #some condition] where [expression in item for] format

Comment: You avoid having to hard code single phrases, while a list can be a good non destructive way to access csv data